# Unable to send id to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe that I want to display only when a hyperlink is clicked. The iframe has a specific id that I'm using the selector to grab.
When I specify the iframe's id in the javascript function it works just fine, but when I attempt to pass the id from the function call in the hyperlink I get no response.

**This Works**

```
<a href="#" onclick="expandMap();"><h3>Map 1</h3></a>
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="https://map.embed.url" width="100%;" 
height="700px" src="about:blank">
</iframe>

<script>
function expandMap() {
   map = $("#myiFrame");
   map.attr("src", map.data("src"));
}
</script>
```

---

**This does not**

```
<a href="#" onclick="expandMap("#myiFrame");"><h3>Map 1</h3></a>
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="https://map.embed.url" width="100%;" 
height="700px" src="about:blank">
</iframe>

<script>
function expandMap(id) {
   map = $(id);
   map.attr("src", map.data("src"));
}
</script>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your quotes.  You can't have un-escaped double quote inside double quotes.  You can use single quotes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="expandMap('#myiFrame');">
```

P.S. I suggest not using inline JavaScript event handlers.  Personally, I would do this:

```
<a href="#" class="expandMap" data-frame="#myiFrame"><h3>Map 1</h3></a>
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="https://map.embed.url" width="100%;" 
height="700px" src="about:blank">
</iframe>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.expandMap').click(function(){
        var frame = $(this).data('frame');
        map = $(frame);
        map.attr("src", map.data("src"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution, and I didn't realize that using inline javascript event handlers were bad practice. There is one syntax error in your code though. You forgot to close the last parenthesis and add the semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Matt: I don't know if inline handlers are bad per se, I just don't like using them.  It's more powerful to bind the events with JavaScript :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are closing the double quotes inside the call to the function:

```
onclick="expandMap("#myiFrame");"
```

should be:

```
onclick="expandMap('#myiFrame');"
```